# Task based PowerShell cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell

I am learning about Tasks and also writing PowerShell cmdlets in C#. I found that connecting to remote machines was very slow, so I wrote this bit of code to speed it up using Tasks. I am hoping to get some feedback regarding the parallel processing and any other pointers in general.

The code is committed to a [Github repo](https://github.com/hsimah/PoshTasks).

TaskCmdlet.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PoshTasks.Cmdlets
{
    public abstract class TaskCmdlet<TIn, TOut> : Cmdlet where TIn : class
        where TOut : class
    {
        #region Parameters

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true)]
        public TIn[] InputObject { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Abstract methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs an action on <paramref name="server"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">The <see cref="object"/> to be processed; null if not processing input</param>
        /// <returns>A <see cref="T"/></returns>
        protected abstract TOut ProcessTask(TIn input = null);

        #endregion

        #region Virtual methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a collection of tasks to be processed
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A collection of tasks</returns>
        protected virtual IEnumerable<Task<TOut>> GenerateTasks()
        {
            List<Task<TOut>> tasks = new List<Task<TOut>>();

            if (InputObject != null)
                foreach (TIn input in InputObject)
                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ProcessTask(input)));
            else
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ProcessTask()));

            return tasks;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs the pipeline output for this cmdlet
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="result"></param>
        protected virtual void PostProcessTask(TOut result)
        {
            WriteObject(result, true);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Processing

        /// <summary>
        /// Processes cmdlet operation
        /// </summary>
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            IEnumerable<Task<TOut>> tasks = GenerateTasks();

            foreach (Task<Task<TOut>> bucket in Interleaved(tasks))
            {
                try
                {
                    Task<TOut> task = bucket.Result;
                    TOut result = task.Result;

                    PostProcessTask(result);
                }
                catch (Exception e) when (e is PipelineStoppedException || e is PipelineClosedException)
                {
                    // do nothing if pipeline stops
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    WriteError(new ErrorRecord(e, e.GetType().Name, ErrorCategory.NotSpecified, this));
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Interleaves the tasks
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tasks">The collection of <see cref="Task{TOut}"/></param>
        /// <returns>An array of task tasks</returns>
        protected Task<Task<TOut>>[] Interleaved(IEnumerable<Task<TOut>> tasks)
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<Task<TOut>>[] buckets = new TaskCompletionSource<Task<TOut>>[tasks.Count()];
            Task<Task<TOut>>[] results = new Task<Task<TOut>>[buckets.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < buckets.Length; i++)
            {
                buckets[i] = new TaskCompletionSource<Task<TOut>>();
                results[i] = buckets[i].Task;
            }

            int nextTaskIndex = -1;

            foreach (Task<TOut> task in tasks)
                task.ContinueWith(completed =>
                {
                    TaskCompletionSource<Task<TOut>> bucket = buckets[Interlocked.Increment(ref nextTaskIndex)];
                    bucket.TrySetResult(completed);
                },
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.None,
                TaskScheduler.Default);

            return results;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

GetRemoteService.cs (a sample implementation)

```
using PoshTasks.Cmdlets;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace PoshTasks.Sample
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "RemoteService")]
    public class GetRemoteService : TaskCmdlet<string, ServiceController[]>
    {
        #region Parameters

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the collection of requested service names
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter]
        public string[] Name { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Processing

        /// <summary>
        /// Processes a single remote service lookup
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="server">The remote machine name</param>
        /// <returns>A collection of <see cref="ServiceController"/>s from the remote machine</returns>
        protected override ServiceController[] ProcessTask(string server)
        {
            ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices(server);

            if (Name != null)
                return services.Where(s => Name.Contains(s.DisplayName)).ToArray();

            return services;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates custom service object and outputs to pipeline
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="result">The collection of remote services</param>
        protected override void PostProcessTask(ServiceController[] result)
        {
            List<dynamic> services = new List<dynamic>();

            foreach (ServiceController service in result)
                services.Add(new
                {
                    Name = service.DisplayName,
                    Status = service.Status,
                    ComputerName = service.MachineName,
                    CanPause = service.CanPauseAndContinue
                });

            WriteObject(services, true);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

If not cloning the repo you will need the `Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies` Nuget package and to reference `System.ServiceProcess`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## General conventions

The old *good* `#region`. Most people (including me) consider them rather bad then good. You should avoid them.

---

> ```
> if (InputObject != null)
>   foreach (TIn input in InputObject)
>       tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ProcessTask(input)));
> else
>   tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ProcessTask()));
> ```

There's not even single curly brace `{}` ;-) I wouldn't complain if it was python but in C# you should *always* use them. Omitting them can cause a real headache.

---

> ```
> protected virtual IEnumerable<Task<TOut>> GenerateTasks()
> {
>   List<Task<TOut>> tasks = new List<Task<TOut>>();
>
>   if (InputObject != null)
>       foreach (TIn input in InputObject)
>           tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ProcessTask(input)));
>   else
>       tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ProcessTask()));
>
>   return tasks;
> }
> ```

In cases like this you can use `yead return` which greatly simplifies the code:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<Task<TOut>> CreateProcessTasks()
{
    if (InputObject == null) 
    {
        yield return Task.Run(() => ProcessTask());
        yield break;
    }

    foreach (var input in InputObject)
    {
        yield return Task.Run(() => ProcessTask(input));
    }
}
```

I think this method doesn't need to be `virtual`. Generating tasks in not something you'd like to implement in each derived class. Consider changing its name to `CreateProcessTasks` as this is what it does. Generate sounds like it would create some random tasks.

---

## async/await

In order for the `async/await` to work you need to actually `await` something but I couldn't find it in your code. Let's try to fix that and introduce few other changes that make your code look better.

I start with the `Interleaved` method... and you actually don't need it. Everything it does can be reduced to a single line:

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Where do I put it? I move this one to the `ProcessRecordCore` method that after this adjustment now looks like this:

```
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    var errorRecords = Task.Run(async () => await ProcessRecordCore()).Result;

    foreach (var errorRecord in errorRecords)
    {
        WriteError(errorRecord);    
    }       
}

private async Task<BlockingCollection<ErrorRecord>> ProcessRecordCore()
{
    var tasks = CreateProcessTasks();

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

    var errorRecords = new BlockingCollection<ErrorRecord>();

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        try
        {
            PostProcessTask(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e) when (e is PipelineStoppedException || e is PipelineClosedException)
        {
            // do nothing if pipeline stops
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorRecords.Add(new ErrorRecord(e, e.GetType().Name, ErrorCategory.NotSpecified, this));
        }
    }

    return errorRecords;
}
```

Notice that `ProcessRecordCore` it's now marked as `async` so you can `await` for it to complete and the `ProcessRecord` uses the `.Wait()` method.

---

There are two more methods that can be simplified. The first one is the `ProcessTask` method where you can use the `?:` ternary operator and don't need the `if`.

```
protected override ServiceController[] ProcessTask(string server)
{
    var services = ServiceController.GetServices(server);

    return 
        Name == null
        ? services
        : services.Where(s => Name.Contains(s.DisplayName)).ToArray();
}
```

or you can go *crazy* and make it a one-liner:

```
return services.Where(s => Name == null || Name.Contains(s.DisplayName)).ToArray();
```

---

The other one is the `PostProcessTask` method that could use some `var`s (like the rest of the code):

```
protected override void PostProcessTask(ServiceController[] result)
{
    var services = new List<dynamic>();

    foreach (var service in result)
    {
        services.Add(new
        {
            Name = service.DisplayName,
            Status = service.Status,
            ComputerName = service.MachineName,
            CanPause = service.CanPauseAndContinue
        });
    }

    WriteObject(services, true);
}
```

---

## IProgress interface

To see the errors right away you may try another approach with the `IProgress<ErrorRecord>`. Here's an example;

```
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    var progress = new Progress<ErrorRecord>(errorRecord =>
    {
        WriteError(errorRecord);    
    });

    var errorRecords = Task.Run(async () => await ProcessRecordCore(progress));     
}

private async Task ProcessRecordCore(IProgress<ErrorRecord> progress)
{
    var tasks = CreateProcessTasks();

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        try
        {
            PostProcessTask(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e) when (e is PipelineStoppedException || e is PipelineClosedException)
        {
            // do nothing if pipeline stops
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            progress.Report(new ErrorRecord(e, e.GetType().Name, ErrorCategory.NotSpecified, this));
        }
    }       
}
```

> One important aspect of this class is that it invokes ProgressChanged (and the Action) in the context in which it was constructed.

See [Reporting Progress from Async Tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html) for more information.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to review this. I'm not sure how review responses work here, so I am commenting. All your style points are valid, it's much cleaner code. I set `CreateProcessTasks()` to be virtual in case there is some pre-processing needed to be done by inheriting classes. In one example there are more PowerShell Parameters defined and that affects the behaviour of the tasks themselves. I suppose this could be moved to the `ProcessTask()` function - I will have a think about this.

Comment: I have an interesting problem using `await`/`async`. A PowerShell cmdlet can only call `WriteObject()` and `WriteError()` on the parent thread. So, I found I couldn't use `await` in `ProcessRecordCore()` as a different thread might be executing the yielded object. I fully appreciate the improvement you made to my code, but this is a limitation I can't seem to figure a way around. If you have any suggestions, please do let me know. I found processing the tasks in parallel improved the performance significantly, so the delay in output is similar to existing Microsoft cmdlets and acceptable.

Comment: @hsimah commenting is perfectly fine ;-) and you're absolutely right. I should have looked into the documentation. I've updated the code and changed the pattern. Now the [`WriteError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writeerror(v=vs.85).aspx) is properly called from the `ProcessRecord` where it's allowed to.

Comment: @hsimah I've added one more example with _immediate_ progress (here error) reporting.

Comment: When I use the new code it's still executing on a different thread in the pool. The `Progress` code is very cool. What I need is something similar to `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher`. [I found a sample](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/11/26/PowerShell-_2D00_-A-cmdlet-that-reports-progress-_2D00_-A-simple-file-downloader-cmdlet.aspx) which uses events to write progress, but I feel this might be a bit much for what I am doing. The Microsoft cmdlet for `Get-Service` does it all synchronously and only outputs at the end, so together we've already outdone them.

Comment: I am releasing this code as a nuget package and would like to credit you as a contributor. Shall I just use the details on your profile here? Cheers again.